# Iterating efficiently through indices of arbitrary order array

Tags: python, arrays, loops, indices

Say I have an arbitrary array of variable order N. For example:
A is a 2x3x3 array is an order 3 array with 2,3, and 3 dimiensions along it's three indices.

I would like to efficiently loop through each element. If I knew a priori the order then I could do something like (in python),

```
#for order 3 
import numpy as np
shape = np.shape(A)
i = 0
while i < shape[0]:
  j = 0
  while j < shape[1]:
    k = 0
    while k < shape[2]:
      #code using i,j,k
      k += 1
    j += 1
  i += 1
```

Now suppose I don't know the order of A, i.e. I don't know a priori the length of `shape`. How can I permute the quickest through all elements of the array?

Comment: Is the array necessarily formatted as a numpy array?

Comment: What are you *actually trying to achieve*? You could do e.g. `for indices in itertools.product(*map(range, shape)):`, but it seems unlikely that this is the best approach.

Comment: Do you need to store the results of the "#code using i,j,k" ?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: An alternative: `for indices in range(a.size): indices = np.unravel_index(i, a.shape)`.

Comment: You could do it recursively, I've written an answer below showing how.

Comment: @AustinKootz: That's getting rather complex, don't you think?  An iterative implementation is given in https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product.  But since we already have that function in the standard library, we could just as well use it, as suggested by jonrsharpe above.  Another easy solution is to use `np.unravel_index()`, or even easier, iterate over `a.flat`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach You may well be right. I simply wanted to provide a useful and understandable method for doing what the OP wanted. The OP probably should use `itertools.product()`, or `np.unravel_index()`. However using those methods would leave them in the dark about how the recursive tool is actually functioning. My example below should help them understand. Then they'll be able to use the other suggested methods productively.

Comment: OP, you might consider accepting one of these answers

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, e.g. iterating over `a.ravel()` or `a.flat`.  However, looping over every single element of an array in a Python loop will never be particularly efficient.

Comment: Iterating over `a.flat` wouldn't allow operations to be done based on location in the original n-dimensional array (the item's i,j,k location). It would work great for applying some function to each term though.

Comment: @AustinKootz That could be trivially achieved by iterating over `enumerate(a.flat)` instead of `a.flat`, just as you would do for plain Python lists.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it matters which index you choose to permute over first, which index you choose to permute over second, etc. because your inner-most while statement will always be executed once per combination of `i`, `j`, and `k`.

Answer (score 0):

If the array of of the format `array = [[[1,2,3,4],[1,2]],[[1],[1,2,3]]]`

You could use the following structure:

```
array = [[[1,2,3,4],[1,2]],[[1],[1,2,3]]]
indices = []
def iter_array(array,indices):
    indices.append(0)
    for a in array:
        if isinstance(a[0],list):
            iter_array(a,indices)
        else:
            indices.append(0)
            for nonlist in a:
                #do something using each element in indices
                #print(indices)
                indices.append(indices.pop()+1)
            indices.pop()
        indices.append(indices.pop()+1)
    indices.pop()

iter_array(array,indices)
```

This should work for the usual nested list "arrays" I don't know if it would be possible to mimic this using numpy's array structure.

Comment: The OP stated that they don't even know the number of dimensions (called the "order" in the post), so you wouldn't know how many loops to nest.

Comment: If we knew the maximum "order" we could preface each `for` statement with `if isinstance(array[i][j],list):` to allow for it to stop at the appropriate level.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how I would call the nested `for` loops recursively, but I feel that that would be the best way to do it.

Comment: I've rewritten it to be recursive. I may make further minor edits for clarity

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the results of your operation (and assuming its a function of A and i,j,k) You'd want to use something like this:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

results = ( (position, code(A,position))
              for indices in itertools.product(*(range(i) for i in np.shape(A))))
```

Then you can iterate the results getting out the position and return value of code for each position. Or convert the generator expression to a list if you need to access the results multiple times.